# macOS: Cannot connect to app store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, high-sierra, keychain

Every time I open the App Store on High Sierra it cannot connect. I've checked the DNS settings, old certificates, keychain access; in short I've completed all [these](https://howtoremove.guide/cannot-connect-app-store-mac-fixed/) steps and still:

[image: app store]

Any ideas? It appears not even to try to load, i.e., that page is immediately there and refreshing doesn't attempt to load anything.

Comment: The screen you showed has the message "An internet connection is required."  It seems it doesn't recognize your connection for some reason, Does your browser work ok?

Comment: Browser's fine, pinging Google is fine. Connection is definitely working.

Answer (score 1):

So the culprit was Little Snitch blocking a process called `commerce`. If you deny access to `commerce` then the App Store will refuse to load. Allow it to make all well again:

[image: commerce]

Comment: Where the heck is this setting though ?   I can see "commerce" running in Activity Monitor, and I'm also trying to find out why my MacBook can happily surf the web, but can't connect to the App Store.  P.S. The Apple Firewall is turned off on my machine...